# Powershell Move Files With Matching Substrings

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to clean up a directory with a ton of files with windows powershell, and so far all the other StackOverflow posts haven't seemed to help me crack my issue.

I have a parent directory named /1/
I have a sub directory named /1/j/

I want to have all of the files in directory /1/ with (J) in any part of their names (including the parenthesis) moved into the /j/ sub directory. Example filename would be: "example filename (J).smc"

Here  is the code I have so far that's not working:

```
$source = 'F:\1\'
$destination = 'F:\1\j'

Get-ChildItem $source -filter *.smc -recurse | Select-String -List -Pattern "(J)" | ForEach-Object {
Move-Item $PSItem.Path -Destination $destination
}
```

I feel like it's something simple, so I apologize if it is! Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: What about `Get-ChildItem -Path 'F:\1\' -Filter *j*.smc | Move-Item -Destination 'F:\1\j'`  ?

Comment: I used *'(j)'* instead of *J* because that sent all the files with j anywhere in the file name to the /1/j/ subfolder. But it worked!

Comment: Your own answer, inspired by Olaf, is definitely the best solution, but as for what you tried: you should have used a `Where-Object` call for filtering, not `Select-String` - the latter is for searching through _string_ output. E.g., `Where-Object Name -match '\(J\)'`

Answer (score 3):

Made it harder than it had to be. Thanks Olaf!

Solution:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'F:\1\' -Filter *'(j)'*.smc | Move-Item -Destination 'F:\1\j'
```

Comment: Nice; but as an aside: `*'(j)'*.smc` works, but  it's generally better to use `'*(j)*.smc'` (quoting around the _whole_ argument) - unlike POSIX-compatible shells, PowerShell itself doesn't interpret `*`, only the target command does, and unlike POSIX-compatible shells, PowerShell is finicky about compound string arguments composed of quoted an unquoted parts; in short: it only works if the first part is _unquoted_; e.g., `Write-Output 'foo'bar` does _not_ work as one would expect.